# main menu hide woo commerce single products tittle

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-interface

> sorry maybe its off topic but i couldn't find any answer in oceanwp and
>   woocommerse forums

i use oceanwp them and elementor for design and my  problem is main menu hide single products tittle

this is the site URL you can see main menu hide product tittle

http://45.32.113.186/wpdemo1/shop/women-black-dress/

this is another issues

http://45.32.113.186/wpdemo1/shop/50-to-do-in-vietnam/

[image: this is the expect]
when page load time i can get this view and if i refresh i get this

[image: break UI]

how can i fix this issues?

note: if is off topic and if some know how to solve this please help to fix this issues thank you

Comment: Set css for your main content area div.
.single-product .site-main{margin-top:70px;} and also use media query for setting the margin in responsive view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open in incognito mode and then check once and let us know if problem exists then fix the design using custom css code.